# Importing existing project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, importerror

Can't import any existing project into Android Studio. Every time I do this, it stuck at **Building 'project-name' Gradle Project info**. And that is annoying.
I have searched for solution but haven't got one.

[image: Building 'project-name' Gradle Project info]

After this, I have to end the process of Android Studio to get rid of this non stoppable task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not stuck , It's take some time to download required libraries for the first time . Please check your internet connection speed. Give it some time to download and install all the libraries. 
If that wont work try these :
1) Just Remove Gradle files from your project folder and retry.
2) Check Gradle path if its not correct correct them ,check on website if update shows do it.

Comment: got that! finally after long time it completed downloads.